# laravel model returning escaped text

Tags: php, string, laravel, escaping

I am getting some data from my database via a model, the data returned needs to be cross platform and for that reason I am wanting to able to be returned encoded/escaped data and unencoded/unescaped data.

**The data I am getting returned at the moment looks like this:**

```
  "content": "<p>Things which the client likes or that you think are an appropriate direction to go in.</p><div>  
<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/zjwS_0WV-1Q\" width=\"425\" height=\"350\"></iframe></div>",
```

Ideally I would like to provide a plain version of this as well without the slashes, the data is return as an array. Is there any way to escape all the data in array?

Comment: Your data is not escaped in db. It is escaped when it was json encoded. and it is normal, because double quotes should be escaped in json string.

Comment: Can I return is something other than JSON?

Comment: your data is not escaped, it's just a string, not json. you can leverage `json` method provided to migrations. Do a migration to add a field (or modify existing one)  `$table->json('content');`. then in your model add `protected $casts = ['content' => 'json'];` then try it out, that might help